# mysql max(timestamp) query nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am looking to get the most updated record in my database using the maxtime stamp value. The db layout is listed below

[image: database layout]

here is my code including the query I am running to retrieve the desired row

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'database',
    database : 'airplanemap'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.error('error connecting' + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id' + connection.threadId);

    connection.query('SELECT name, baggageno, destination, max(ts) FROM map', function (err, results, fields) {

        if(err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
        return;
        }

        if(results.length > 0) {
            var myresult = results[0];
            console.log('results ' + myresult['name'] + ' ' + myresult['baggageno'] + ' ' + myresult['destination'] + ' ' + myresult['max(ts)']);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('no results');
        }
    })
});
```

The results I receive is

jane 2 new york Sat Mar 14 2015 02:25:03 GMT-0400

From this it returns the highest timestamp but the wrong column value for name, baggageno and destination

It should be

john 5 toronto Sat Mar 14 2015 02:25:03 GMT-0400

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I am expecting one row value in the results array the row in the table with the most recent timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your query is returning 4 rows:

```
[
  { name: 'john', baggageno: 5, destination: 'toronto', 'max(ts)': 'Sat Mar 14 2015 02:25:03 GMT-0400' },
  { name: 'jill', baggageno: 1, destination: 'karachi', 'max(ts)': 'Sat Mar 14 2015 02:25:03 GMT-0400' },
  { name: 'jane', baggageno: 2, destination: 'new york', 'max(ts)': 'Sat Mar 14 2015 02:25:03 GMT-0400' },
  { name: 'jim', baggageno: 5, destination: 'glasgow', 'max(ts)': 'Sat Mar 14 2015 02:25:03 GMT-0400' },
]
```

and you're picking the first row out of that result set, so that is why you're seeing what you're seeing (although the ordering of the rows is up to the server because you did not request a specific ordering).

You need to add some kind of filter if you're trying to find the record(s) with the latest `ts` value. For example, using a join might look something like:

```sql
SELECT map.*
FROM map
LEFT JOIN map map2 ON map.name = map2.name
  AND map.baggageno = map2.baggageno
  AND map.destination = map2.destination
  AND map.ts < map2.ts
WHERE map2.name IS NULL
```

You can also do something similar except using an inner join, if you want to do it that way.

Comment: when I execute your query it still returns 4 rows in order of the names, so the first row row[0] contains jane, why the next row[1] is jill. How do i get it to return the row with the max timestamp only, I just want result to contain one row